# Magento: Assign all products to New store View after creating substore

Tags: magento

I have main site and created multiple stores for different langues from magento admin.

Requirement - All categories and products need to be automatically displayed for new store.

Problem - All categories are displaying ok but all products are not displaying as these are displaying in main site. How can I achieve this?

What I have already done:

1. Magento version: 1.9
2. All categories and products need display on all stores
3. Multiple stores are created successfully

What else can I do?

Comment: suppose just i add store, not individual website, just store, how can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your manage products page, click select all, change the action dropdown to say "Change Attributes" and click submit. Then, on the websites tab, make sure your new site is checked in the "Add Product to Websites" area, and click save.

Comment: I solved the problem and answer posted. But Images are not displaying there. Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Changed permission of media directory to 777 and its done now.